# angularjs count duplicate values in array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I'm working with AngularJS.
I have an array of objects like this:

```
 $scope.documents =
   [
        {
            "id": "221",
            "activate": "t"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "221",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "221",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "221",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "activate": "t"        
        },
        {
            "id": "221",
            "activate": "t"        
        }

    ]
```

I need an angularjs function to count the number of repeated values in the array of objects.

Something like this:

```
  $scope.count = function(param) {

    angular.forEach($scope.preguntas, function(value, key) {
        if (value.id == param){
        ........
        ........
        }
    });

  };
```

but I'm not sure how I can do.

I hope the result is something like this:

```
count(221);
5
```

Any of you have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

Just increment a count variable in your if statement and return it.

```
$scope.count = function(param) {
  var count = 0;

  $scope.documents.forEach(function(document) {
      if(document.id === param.toString() {
        count++;
      }
  });

  return count;
};
```

And your markup:

```
<div>{{count(221)}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use lo-dash, you can do this:

```
_.countBy(documents, 'id')['221']
```

https://lodash.com/docs#countBy